# Переназначение целочисленных индексов по порядку в случайном столбце sql таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица (не знаю, как оформить здесь)

```
Буква | Цифра
А | 1
И | 3
П | 7
У | 7
Я | 4
```

Нужно проапдейтить строки так чтобы цифры стали идти по порядку, но в той же последовательности. То есть придти к виду

```
Буква | Цифра
А | 1
И | 2
П | 4
У | 4
Я | 3
```

В примере мы видим, что изначально цифры идут от 1 до 7, пропуская 2, 5 и 6. В итоге они стали идти от 1 до 4 уже без пропусков. При этом одинаковые цифры заменились на одинаковые, а порядок записей (если упорядочить по столбцу с цифрами) сохранился. 
Не приложу ума как сделать, может есть какие-то стандартные функции. То ли переменную со счетчиком использовать, то ли что.

Comment: абсолютно не ясно что нужно получить - *чтобы цифры стали идти по порядку, но в той же последовательности* - это как? из примера тем более не понятно, ибо там и не по порядку, и не в той же последовательности, и вообще, это другие цифры

Comment: Эм. Ну это ж БД. Для удобства можно упорядочить по второму столбцу, но для реализма я их перемешал. В примере мы видим, что цифры идут от 1 до 7, пропустив 2 и 5. Во второй таблице они сохраняют свои места, но цифры идут уже без пропусков от 1 до 5 (и если упорядочить по цифрам они бы остались в той же последовательности).
Стоит учесть, что цифры могут повторяться. Тогда и заменяться на новую, но одну и ту же.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие, приведите в порядок свой вопрос

Comment: Вообще с комментарием стало понятнее, мне кажется стоит информацию из комментария перенести в вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос поправил, перенеся данные из комментария.

Comment: *кстати, под индексами в теории и практике БД понимается [несколько иное](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_(%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)), поэтому такие заголовки вводят в заблуждение*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите нормализовать нумерацию в соответствии с порядком старой.

> может есть какие-то стандартные функции

Здесь подойдёт функция `DENSE_RANK`:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
        [цифра],
        [новая_цифра] = DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY [цифра])
    FROM
        [TableName]
)
UPDATE data
SET [цифра] = [новая_цифра];
```

`ROW_NUMBER` здесь не подойдёт, т.к. он даст одинаковым старым номерам разные новые номера.

Comment: Спасибо, именно этот вариант понравился, работает (про производительность ничего, конечно и предположить не могу). Не знаком с функцией DENSE_RANK () (с sql знаком поверхностно, но понадобился в проекте на C#).

Answer (score 1):

```
update [table]
set цифра= t.цифра
from(
select row_number() over(order by  цифра) цифра, буква from [table]) t
where [table].буква = t.буква;
```

Comment: Не пробовал, но смысл примерно понял, спасибо! Но разве этот способ не предполагает, что цифра повторяется только один раз?

Comment: Я отвечал на вопрос, когда там еще не было повторов. :-) Но это не проблема, достаточно использовать DENSE_RANK вместо ROW_NUMBER

Comment: И правда, тоже работает. Смог только плюсануть ответ. Не известно еще какой работает быстрее =)